# How would I specify intervals?

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I am new to latex, and would like to plot a graph where the x-axis has intervals. I have this sample code that is not interval:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}  %Changed 1cm to 10cm so plot is visible RMS
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

Plotting from data:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Solubility [g per 100 g water]},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=120,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates{
    (0,40)(20,60)
    };
    \legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O, random, yo}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled image]
Additionally, let's say that I have two figure similar and would like to combine them together horizontally, how could I do this and add a text box right under?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need `x tick label as interval,` and to plot two plots side by side, you may use `subfigure` from `subcaption` package or use two `\addplot` commands inside the same `axis` environment. adjust the wodth by the `width` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Intervals

I cannot post a picture in a comment, so I use the answer function. Do you mean something like this (you have to look closely in order to be able to see the fine tick lines):

[image]

In the current [pgfplots documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (Revision 1.12) you find on page 286 (Chapter 4.15) the following example (see comment from [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar)):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval=0.9,
x tick label as interval,
xmin=2003,xmax=2030,
ymin=0,ymax=140,
xticklabel={
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$
-- $\pgfmathprintnumber{\nexttick}$},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={
rotate=90,anchor=east,
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}
]
\addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue!40!white]
coordinates
{(2003,40) (2005,100) (2006,15)
(2010,90) (2020,120) (2030,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Leading to

[image]

> Description of `x tick label as interval`: Allows to treat tick labels
>   as intervals; that means the tick positions denote the interval
>   boundaries. If there are n positions, (n  1) tick labels will be
>   generated, one for each interval.

### Two plots Side-by-Side

As [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar) mentioned you can have two plots side by side. Look for `Vertical Alignment with baseline` (Chapter 4.19.2 ff.) and `Horizontal Alignment` (Chapter 4.19.3 ff.) in the [pgfplots documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (Chapter 4.19. Alignment Options).

Here's an example:

```
\pgfplotsset{domain=-1:1}
% Diagram 1
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=A normal sized $x$ label]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=*] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\hspace{0.15cm} % <-- space between the diagrams
%
% Diagram 2
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^N n_i $ }]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=*] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]